# If $[f(t) > l \implies f'(t) <0]$, then $\sup_{t \in [0, T]} f(t) \le \max \{f(0), l\}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to prove *Lemma 3.7* in this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414998000180), i.e.,

> **Lemma** Let $T \in [0, \infty)$ and $f:[0, T] \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable. If $l \in (0, \infty)$ such that $\{t \in [0, T] ; f(t) > l\} \subset \{t \in [0, T] ; f'(t) <0\}$, then $\sup_{t \in [0, T]} f(t) \le \max \{f(0), l\}$.

Could you confirm if my below attempt is fine?

---

**Proof** Assume the contrary that there is $t_0 \in [0, T]$ such that $f(t_0) > \max \{f(0), l\}$. Then $t_0 >0$ and there is $t_1 \in [0, t_0]$ such that $f(t_1) = \sup_{t \in [0, t_0]} f(t)$. Then $f(t_1) > l$. So $t_1 >0$ and $f'(t_1) <0$. This implies there is $t_2 \in [0, t_1]$ such that $f(t_2) > f(t_1)$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: [+1] It is fine.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you so much for your verification! I'm happy to see you again.